# Is it possible to create a symlink to the latest file in a directory?

Tags: unix

I have a home directory in my unix box. I would like to setup a number or shortcuts in it to point to the latest file in another directory and the link will update if a newer file is created.

Is this possible?

So far I able to get the latest file:

```
ls -lrt | tail -n1
```

Thanks

**[EDIT]**

Perhaps I could even create a shell instead of a softlink which finds the latest file and returns it so I can open/grep/delete etc?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In bash, this will make a link to the latest file or directory in "target-directory" called "latest":

```
ln -s target-directory/`ls -rt target-directory | tail -n1` latest
```

And this will wait for a change in "target-directory" before returning:

```
inotifywait -e attrib target-directory
```

Comment: Thanks man. I just have one issue with this. If a newer file was created the link would no longer be up to date?

Comment: You can run the above two commands in an infinite loop. Make a link to the latest file, then wait for another change and make a new link. ln may need you to rm the old link before making a new one. I forget.

Answer (score 0):

I found this.

ln -s "$(ls -t | head -n 1)" latest_file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).