# Get an auto updated symbolic link to the latest file, based on grep on file name

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, inotify, inotifywait

So adapting [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626120/is-it-possible-to-create-a-symlink-to-the-latest-file-in-a-directory) a bit is very close to the solution:

```
ln -s target-directory/`ls -rt target-directory | grep .log | tail -n1` latest
```

but how can I actually **continously update** the sym-link when a new file appears in the directory?

Can this be archived by using `inotifywait`? How could I install such a job on my system which takes care in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that parsing `ls` output can be error prone. See [bash FAQ 99](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/099).

If `inotifywait` tool is available, you can do something like to get update the symlink.

```
#!/bin/bash

function newest_log
{
    files=(*.log)
    newest=${files[0]}
    for f in "${files[@]}"; do
        if [[ $f -nt $newest ]]; then
            newest=$f
      fi
    done

    echo $newest
}

while inotifywait -e modify target-directory; do
    ln -s target-directory/$(newest_log) latest
done
```

You can either run this script directly or setup a service like *systemd* service.

Comment: This works perfect - Thanks! I automated the system-boot & alive-check using supervisord.